# Optimistic concurrency exception due to unnecessary updates

Tags: entity-framework

I have an object Account which is referenced by many objects Payment. I am seeing that when I change the state of the payment the Account's rowversion property Version is also updated with a SQL like this:

```
update [dbo].[Account]
set    @p = 0
where  (([Id] = 2606 /* @0 */)
        and ([Version] = 0x0000000000000C8C /* @1 */))

select [Version]
from   [dbo].[Account]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [Id] = 2606 /* @0 */
```

Absolutely no other updates on the Account in that transaction. I checked my code several times and do not see any modifications on the Account object. Also I have overridden the DbContext's SaveChanges and I do not see an entry for the Account object in an EntityState.Modified...

The big problem is not only the unnecessary update but the fact that several payments associated with an account may get updated at the same time and of course an optimistic concurrency exception will be thrown and the transaction will roll-back and must be repeated.

Can someone suggest what to check/fix/change in my code to stop all that.

Comment: Pls, update your questions with more information - which ver. of EF, how are the entities declared, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using EF4.x, then there is a hotfix to correct this issue.
I had the same problem and I can confirm the hotfix corrects it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624

> FIX: The principal entity in an SQL application generates unnecessary updates when the application uses the Entity Framework in the .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 0):

An addition to [Matthew Artz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243445/299164):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624 mentions:

> Contact Microsoft Customer Service and Support to obtain the hotfix.

Here you can request and obtain the hotfix: [Request hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2390624)

You'll receive an email with a download URL. Make sure you only copy the URL between `(` and `)`.